# Enable https on EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, https

I have an elastic public IP for my EC2 instance. I have an Nginx server running on it (and nodejs as a backend server). I'd like to enable HTTPS access to my server.

My questions:

1. Can I create an SSL certificate (not self-signed) using just my elastic public IP?
2. If not, my department has a domain. let's say, **https://www.example.com**. How can I enter the record (and where?) so that **https://www.example.com/base-route** points to my elastic public IP without affecting any existing routes? If this is possible, do I create ssl certificate for **https://www.example.com** or **https://www.example.com/base-route**
3. If I create a new SSL certificate for https://www.example.com/base-route, will it have any impact on the existing certificate for https://www.example.com/?
4. Will new routes, say /route-2 on linked domain name point to correct route. For example, **https://www.example.com/base-route/route-2** point to http://ip-address/route-2

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes

2-4. SSL certificate is installed on a domain/subdomain. So, you will use the same SSL certificate for

```
https://example.com/subdomain/
```

and

```
https://example.com/
```

and any other links under your example.com domain.
You would only need to configure your nginx to point your subdirectories to the your applications

Comment: Thank you. Can you please provide more details on your first answer?

Comment: “1. Yes” - really? I’m not aware of any recognised public CA that issues certs for IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to create a new domain name for your EC2 instance, e.g. `something.example.com`, as an A record pointing to your elastic IP. Then you can open ports 80 and 443 in the *Security group* and create a new SSL certificate for example through [letsencrypt.org](https://letsencrypt.org). That will give you an independent HTTPS URL https://something.example.com

If you still want to have it under http://example.com/something you’ll have to configure a reverse proxy on the existing web server (assuming it’s a different server than this one we talk about). That’d be a topic for another question though.

Hope that helps :)